# 3D plot of a anisotropy of young's modulus

Tags: plotting

Sorry, I know a lot of similar questions have been asked before, but I just can't find one that exactly describes my problem.

How can i draw a 3D plot of anisotrophy of young's modulus from following equation[image]

As he drawn in Mathematica
http://demonstrations.wolfram.com/AnisotropicElasticity/

Looking forward to yours help

Comment: Use `SphericalPlot3D`, it is the easiest way.

Comment: You can download the `.nb` file from the demonstration and see for yourself ;) [use the link that says `Download Author Code »(preview »)`]

Answer (score 4):

I get asked this a lot (year 2023), so I decided to edit this old answer in an extended setting so I can refer to it. The old short version is kept at the bottom. The long version (which can be used for any anisotropic material) is given now.

---

**Extended answer**

Sometimes you want to visualize the stiffness of a material in some engineering sense. Here, the Young's modulus of a material with stiffness $\mathbb{C}$, compliance $\mathbb{S} = \mathbb{C}^{-1}$ in spatial direction $\boldsymbol{n} \in R^3$ defined as

\begin{equation}
Y(\boldsymbol{n},\mathbb{S}) = (\mathbb{S} \cdot \boldsymbol{n}^{\otimes 4})^{-1}
= (S_{ijkl} n_i n_j n_k n_l)^{-1}
\end{equation}

offers a good option reflecting the material symmetry. In most projects, you dont have the compliance but the material stiffness $\mathbb{C}$ (or its components $C_{ijkl}$), so we need some things in order to compute and visualize $Y$.

In the following block I will define:

1. The general triclinic stiffness matrix (6x6 matrix) in normalized Voigt notation (also referred in papers as the Mandel notation with index convention 11-22-33-23-13-12, see, e.g., [wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Voigt_notation)). Any material from a special material class, e.g., cubic materials or transversely isotropic materials, can be written as a special case, provided you know the relations between the components, see, e.g., [TU München](https://wiki.tum.de/display/zfp/Elasticity+tensor+in+anisotropic+materials) for some important cases in Voigt notation (**not** normalized)
2. The stiffness matrix for transversely isotorpic materials
3. The stiffness matrix for cubic materials
4. The computation of the compliance matrix
5. The general plot routine for Young's modulus in 3D

Implementation

```
TriclinicStiffnessMatrix[
   c1111_, c1122_, c1133_, c1123_, c1113_, c1112_,
   c2222_, c2233_, c2223_, c2213_, c2212_,
   c3333_, c3323_, c3313_, c3312_,
   c2323_, c2313_, c2312_,
   c1313_, c1312_,
   c1212_] := Module[
   {m, f},
   m = {
     {c1111, c1122, c1133, c1123, c1113, c1112},
     {0, c2222, c2233, c2223, c2213, c2212},
     {0, 0, c3333, c3323, c3313, c3312},
     {0, 0, 0, c2323, c2313, c2312},
     {0, 0, 0, 0, c1313, c1312},
     {0, 0, 0, 0, 0, c1212}
     };
   Do[m[[i, j]] = m[[j, i]], {i, 2, 6}, {j, 1, i - 1}];
   f = ConstantArray[1, {6, 6}];
   f[[1 ;; 3, 4 ;; 6]] = Sqrt[2];
   f[[4 ;; 6, 1 ;; 3]] = Sqrt[2];
   f[[4 ;; 6, 4 ;; 6]] = 2;
   m*f
   ];
TriclinicStiffnessMatrix::usage = 
  "TriclinicStiffnessMatrix[c1111,c1122,c1133,c1123,c1113,c1112,c2222,\
c2233,c2223,c2213,c2212,c3333,c3323,c3313,c3312,
c2323,c2313,c2312,c1313,c1312,c1212] returns the matrix \
representation of the stiffness of a material in normalized Voigt \
notation (also referred as Mandel notation) based on the index \
convention {{1,1},{2,2},{3,3},{2,3},{1,3},{1,2}} (there are other \
conventions, e.g., the index convention used in Abaqus is different). \
The normalized Voigt notation is algebraically advantageous, since \
computation of the compliance is simply the matrix inverse in the \
normalized Voigt notation and the eigenvalues of the matrix are the \
eigenvalues of the original fourth-order stiffness tensor.";
TransverselyIsotropicStiffnessMatrix[c1111_, c1133_, c3333_, c2323_, 
   c1212_] := TriclinicStiffnessMatrix[
   c1111, c1111 - 2*c1212, c1133, 0, 0, 0,
   c1111, c1133, 0, 0, 0,
   c3333, 0, 0, 0,
   c2323, 0, 0,
   c2323, 0,
   c1212
   ];
CubicStiffnessMatrix[c1111_, c1122_, c1212_] := 
  TriclinicStiffnessMatrix[
   c1111, c1122, c1122, 0, 0, 0,
   c1111, c1122, 0, 0, 0,
   c1111, 0, 0, 0,
   c1212, 0, 0,
   c1212, 0,
   c1212
   ];
ComplianceMatrix[stiffnessMatrix_] := 
  Simplify@Inverse[stiffnessMatrix];
YoungsModulusPlot[stiffnessMatrix_] := Module[
   {compliance, n, phi, theta, n2, ym},
   compliance = ComplianceMatrix[stiffnessMatrix];
   n = {Cos[phi]*Sin[theta], Sin[phi]*Sin[theta], Cos[theta]};
   n2 = TensorProduct[n, n];
   n2 = {
     n2[[1, 1]],
     n2[[2, 2]],
     n2[[3, 3]],
     n2[[2, 3]]*Sqrt[2],
     n2[[1, 3]]*Sqrt[2],
     n2[[1, 2]]*Sqrt[2]};
   ym = 1/(n2 . compliance . n2);
   SphericalPlot3D[ym, {theta, 0, Pi}, {phi, 0, 2 Pi}, 
    AxesLabel -> {"x1", "x2", "x3"}]
   ];
```

If you have access to the 21 stiffness components of a triclinic material, you can represent its stifness as follows

```
MatrixForm[TriclinicStiffnessMatrix @@ Array[a, 21]]
```

[image: Triclinic stiffness matrix in normalized Voigt notation]

For a cubic material you get

```
MatrixForm@CubicStiffnessMatrix[c1111, c1122, c1212]
```

[image: Cubic stiffness matrix]

The main advantage of the normalized Voigt notation is that the material compliance can be computated simply by the matrix inverse (the normalized Voigt notation is algebraically equivalent to the original fourth-order tensors as linear maps between symmetric second-order tenors). For instance, for a given cubic stiffness its compliance given in normalized Voigt notation is

```
MatrixForm@ComplianceMatrix[CubicStiffnessMatrix[c1111, c1122, c1212]]
```

[image: Cubic compliance matrix]

Now we have everything we need to compute Young's modulus in direction $\boldsymbol{n} \in R^3$, defined with $N_{ij} = n_{j}n_{j}$ as

$$
Y(\boldsymbol{n}, \mathbb{S})
=
(S_{ijkl}N_{ij}N_{kl})^{-1}
=
(\underline{N}^T \underline{\underline{S}} \ \underline{N})^{-1}
$$

where $\underline{N}$ and $\underline{\underline{S}}$ denote the vector and matrix representation of the tensors in normalized Voigt notation. Use the plot routine defined above, e.g., for a transversely isotropic material and a cubic one (I am only also computing the eigenvalues to check that the materials are positive definite = physically sensible)

```
stiffnesses = {
   TransverselyIsotropicStiffnessMatrix[5, 1, 7, 2, 1],
   CubicStiffnessMatrix[10, 1, 2]
   };
Eigenvalues /@ stiffnesses
YoungsModulusPlot /@ stiffnesses
```

[image: Eigenvalues and plots]

---

**Old short answer**

I will define Young's modulus viewed in tensile direction $\boldsymbol{n}$ of a material with compliance $\mathbb{S}$, being the inverse of the stiffness $\mathbb{C}$, i.e., $\mathbb{C} = \mathbb{S}^{-1}$ (in the sense of the inverse of second-order symmetric tensors), as <s>done in this publication</s> (not longer online)

<s>http://www.uni-magdeburg.de/ifme/zeitschrift_tm/2001_Heft2/Boehlke_Brueggeman.pdf</s>

\begin{equation}
Y(\boldsymbol{n},\mathbb{S}) = (\mathbb{S} \cdot \boldsymbol{n}^{\otimes 4})^{-1}
= (S_{ijkl} n_i n_j n_k n_l)^{-1}
\end{equation}

In the following code I create the compliance of a cubic material and plot Young's modulus with `SphericalPlot3D`

```
(*tensile direction*)
n = {Cos[phi]*Sin[theta], Sin[phi]*Sin[theta], Cos[theta]};
(*Basic tensors*)
I2 = IdentityMatrix@3;
IdI = TensorProduct[I2, I2];
I4 = TensorTranspose[IdI, {1, 3, 2, 4}];
IS = (I4 + TensorTranspose[I4, {1, 2, 4, 3}])/2;
(*Projectors of cubic materials*)
Pc1 = 1/3*IdI;
Dc = ConstantArray[0, {3, 3, 3, 3}];
Dc[[1, 1, 1, 1]] = 1;
Dc[[2, 2, 2, 2]] = 1;
Dc[[3, 3, 3, 3]] = 1;
Pc2 = Dc - Pc1;
Pc3 = IS - Pc1 - Pc2;
(*Spectral represention of cubic compliance*)
comp = 1/l1*Pc1 + 1/l2*Pc2 + 1/l3*Pc3;
l1 = 10;
l2 = 3;
l3 = 8;
(*Young's modulues*)
Y = (Total[comp*TensorProduct[n, n, n, n], Infinity])^(-1) // Simplify;
(*Plot*)
SphericalPlot3D[Y, {theta, 0, Pi}, {phi, 0, 2 Pi}]
```

[image]

Comment: Thanx for your help but still i have some problem could you please help me little more in my case C11 = 354.06, C12 = 100.20, C44 = 170 and S11 = 0.003227305, S12 = -0.000711874, S44 = 0.005882353 (all units in GPa) by using these values plot should be spherical but it not

Comment: @Mauricio Lobos Fernández, can you also show the % Poisson ratio % 1. Maximum / 2. Minimum / 3. Average and % Shear modulus % 1. Maximum / 2. Minimum / 3. Average, both are also important, thanking you!

Comment: That depends on the definition you use and usually the number of variables are too high to plot.

Answer (score 3):

```
 e[n_, s11_, b1_] := 1/(s11 - b1 Total[Times @@@ Subsets[n^2, {2}]])
 SphericalPlot3D[
   e[FromSphericalCoordinates[{1, p, t}], 2, 3],
   {p, 0, Pi}, {t, -Pi, Pi}]
```

[image]

Comment: Thanx for your help @george2079 after pasting the code in Mathematica i just get empty frame could you be help me little more whats going wrong?

Comment: if you have an older version that doesn't have `FromSphericalCoordinates` replace that with `{Cos[t] Sin[p], Sin[p] Sin[t], Cos[p]}`

Comment: After replacing the FromSphericalCoordinates into {Cos[t] Sin[p], Sin[p] Sin[t], Cos[p]} still getting the empty frame i dont know why??

Comment: @george2079, can you also show the % Poisson ratio % 1. Maximum / 2. Minimum / 3. Average and % Shear modulus % 1. Maximum / 2. Minimum / 3. Average, both are also important, thanking you!